# How to change applicationId without changing packagename?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any way to change applicationId without changing packagename in android studio?
As read some where i changed applicationid from flavors in project module setting. but doing this getting

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.myapplicationid'
```

Is there any idea how to do this?

and my gradle is after changing flavor

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myapplicationid'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
....
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set applicationId from defaultConfig and remove productFlavors from build.gradle file (I've tested, it should work):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplicationid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
....
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If you look carefully, I removed

```
productFlavors {
}
```

part

*Also, don't forget to update the google-services.json*

Comment: hi @Natig Babayev , doing the same but this is ---Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.myapplicationid'  i am getting

Comment: @user9348691 in that case you should update google-services.json for new application id.

Comment: @user9348691 You're welcome. I think you can mark answer as correct answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare different applicationId like this

```
 android {  
      flavorDimensions "Flavors1"
            productFlavors {
                Flavors1{
                    applicationId "com.myapplicationid1"
                           }

                Flavors2{
                    applicationId "com.myapplicationid2"
                           }
            }
    }
```

If you want to change the applicationId just update in `defaultConfig`

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your_new.id"
}
```

**Don't forgot to update the `google-services.json` if you have used**

Comment: but what if i want only one applicationid

Comment: then why you need productFlavors ?

Comment: I want to change applicationid from existing one

Comment: updated the answer,may you have forgot to update the google-services.json

Answer (score 1):

You can declare multiple Flavors for your application like this

```
productFlavors {
    MainApp {
        applicationId = "com.company.app"
    }
    NewAppFlavor {
        applicationId = "com.company.newapp"
    }
}
```

and build your application and sign using this flavor and you can change between different flavors via [build variants option in android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Answer (score 1):

2 steps to answer your question:

- Change applicationId in your app gradle to the new one
- Change package_name of google-services.json to the new one

If you got an error *No matching client found for package name...* when doing so, then just try steps as follows and it worked for me:

- Remove **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** out of your app gradle.
- Sync Project with Gradle File -> Clean build
- Make sure if your applicationId is valid
- Change your **applicationId** to the new one to make sure it works without errors while built.
- Add **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** to your app gradle again
- Change package_name of google-services.json to the new one like step 3
- Build successfully